# ts action scope issue

Tags: typescript, scope

I declare `const test`, and redeclare it in if and function, it's work, why?

if I declare `test` in the if or the function, the console.log(test) is errored.

```
[ts] Block-scoped variable 'test' used before its declaration.
```

if I don't declare it, it's work, why?

```js
const test = 'this is a test';

if (true) {
  // console.log(test);  // error, test is not declaration
  const test = "this is add word" 
  console.log(test) // this is add word
}

if(true) {
  console.log(test) // this is a test
}

const work = () => {
  const test = "this is a work!"
  console.log(test) // this is a work!
}
work()
console.log(test) // this is a test
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: 1.`const` is not redeclared, I can redeclare it in if and function

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with redeclaration.  _Read the error message_.  You can't use it before you declare it.

Comment: if I don't redeclare it, it's work, but I redeclare the const in the `function` or the `if`,  the `test` out of  `if` and `function` does not work in the `if` and `function`

Comment: **Read the error message**! What don't you understand?

Comment: why I redeclare in `if` and `function`, I couldn't use the `test` outside before

Comment: **Because you cannot use a variable before you declare it**.

Comment: the outside `test` couldn't use?

Comment: No, because you redeclared it in that block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short version of your problem...

You declare `test` in the global scope.

`const` and `let` are block-scoped (rather than `var` which is function-scoped) so you when you get to some curly braces, you also get a new scope.

So inside the curly braces, you have a new scope, within which you have decided to declare a new block-scoped variable with the same name `test`. Inside of those curly braces, your local variable is the only one that exists - otherwise there would be intense confusion over which variable you intend.

Ultimately, if you intend to use the outer `test`, don't declare another variable with the same name.

If you intended to overwrite the original variable, you should use `let` in place of `const` and don't specify the `let` keyword again in new scopes.

```
const test = 'this is a test';

if (true) {
    console.log(test); // this is a test
    const test2 = "this is add word";
    console.log(test2); // this is add word
}

if(true) {
    console.log(test); // this is a test
}

const work = () => {
    const test = "this is a work!";
    console.log(test); // this is a work!
}

work()
console.log(test); // this is a test
```